# Office 365 Management API always returning last 24 hours data

Tags: office365, office365api

I am trying to fetch audit log data from Office 365 using O365 Managment Activity APIs. I am facing this issue that all my requests are returning data for last 24 hours, even when I pass a startTime & endTime in the original request.

Below is the url I am forming for my request. Here I am trying to get data for last 3 hours. I also tried the same with last 3 days but same result.

```
https://manage.office.com/api/v1.0//activity/feed/subscriptions/content?PublisherIdentifier=&contentType=Audit.SharePoint&startTime=2017-11-24T13:52:43.6236735Z&endTime=2017-11-24T16:52:45.0966735Z
```

In my response I get a nextpage URI but it has starttime & endtime as last 24 hours.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office-365/office-365-management-activity-api-reference#list-available-content) provide information on the proper timestamp format for `startTime` and `endTime`:

```
YYYY-MM-DD
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
```

It also states that by default only events of the last 24 hours are returned if `startTime` and `endTime` aren't present (in this case it seems to fallback to the default because they are malformed). Furthermore they can't be more than 24 hours apart.

The API seems to accept the improper timestamps when there's no `nextpage` query parameter, as soon as this parameter is present the api actually returns an unhelpful `AF50004` error.